# SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns is not working "XML Parsing Error: not well-formed"

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, jquery, spservices, spcascadedropdowns

I am working on a sharepoint online team site. and i want to define a Cascade drop down for main and sub categories. so i follow the steps mentioned in this [Demo](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/cascading-of-lookup-dropdown-fields-on-sharepoint-2013-and-o/). Where in my case i created 3 lists inside the root site as follow:-

1. Main Category list.
2. Sub Category list. which have a lookup column referencing the Main Category, as follow:-
   [image]
3. Responsibility list. which have 2 lookup columns; one referencing the Main Category while the other referecning he Sub Category list.

Then inside the Responsibility list's New  form i added this script to implement the cascading lists:-

```
<script src="/Resources/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>  
<script src="/Resources/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script> // i download this from http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/ 
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function ()  
{  
    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns(  
    {  
        relationshipList: "Sub Category",  
        relationshipListParentColumn: "Main Category",  
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",  
        parentColumn: "ResponsibilityMainCategory",  
        childColumn: "ResponsibilitySubCategory",  
        debug: true  
    });  
});  
</script>
```

but this will not have any effect. where inside the New form, all the main and sub categories will be shown.

here is a screen shot of how the 2 fields looks like inside my New form:-
[image]

and when i checked the Firefox Console i find these 2 errors regarding "XML parsing", as follow, but i am not sure what are these errors and if they are related to my problem:-
[image]

So can anyone advice how to get my Cascade drop-down lists working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `_x0020_` to replace space in your code.

For example:

```
relationshipList: "Sub_x0020_Category"
```